# Different versions of TLS in record layer and handshake layer

Tags: security, ssl, openssl

There is application that uses OpenSSL 1.0.2g. Application is able to receive incoming connections and initiate outbound connection. Application sends ClientHello message during create outbound connection. 
In this time I see that versions of TLS are different in record layer and handshake layer.

[image]

It's not clear why it happens. The following flags are used to set in global context.

`SSL_CTX_set_options(ssl_list[i].ctx, SSL_OP_NO_SESSION_RESUMPTION_ON_RENEGOTIATION | SSL_OP_CIPHER_SERVER_PREFERENCE| SSL_OP_NO_SSLv2 | SSL_OP_NO_SSLv3 | SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1 | SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1_1);`

What can be wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Comment: ***"What can be wrong?"*** - Nothing is wrong; that's the protocol operating as expected. There's a record layer protocol and a handshake protocol. The record layer carries the TLS payload. Also see [RFC 5246](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5246). The real question is, why are there two different version, but that's best answered on another site.

Comment: Yes, it's expected behavior according to RFC, but it's not clear why in some cases TLS versions are the same for Record Layer and Handshake Layer. I've asked question on [Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/). Thanks!